# Azure SDK for node is rounding large numbers in JSON responses

Tags: node.js, azure

I've been looking into building a REST api using the Azure SDK for node (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node).  I have a simple MessageTable in Azure tablestore - the PartitionKey is a device identifier (messages belong to a specific messaging device) and the RowKey is a number that identifies the message.

The problem is that the RowKey is a very big number which usually ends with a load of 9's (it's a 'reverse-timestamp'), and the node-azure library is rounding this number up when data is returned.  See example JSON response below:

```
{
"id":"http://xxx.table.core.windows.net/MessageTable(PartitionKey='12345',RowKey='2520801590159999999')",
"link":"MessageTable(PartitionKey='12345',RowKey='2520801590159999999')",
"updated":"2012-03-13T15:53:34Z",
"etag":"W/\"datetime'2011-11-24T13%3A36%3A41.9555578Z'\"",
"PartitionKey":12345,
"RowKey":2520801590160000000,
"Timestamp":"2011-11-24T13:36:41.955Z",
...other results removed for brevity
}
```

The "id" and "link" elements show the correct RowKey of 2520801590159999999; the "RowKey" element shows a rounded version of this: 2520801590160000000.

Anyone know what's going on?

I've also logged this question - I'm sure it's the same root cause:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683515/journey-routing-fails-due-to-number-rounding

Edit @smarx:
Test code reproduced below.  When running, going to http://localhost:8080/devices/12345/messages gives the json output sampled above.  Azure table is MessageTable, partition key is deviceId (12345), rowkey is messageId (2520801590159999999).

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var azure = require('azure');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var tableService = azure.createTableService( '[ACCOUNT_NAME]', '[ACCOUNT_KEY]' );
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

app.get('/devices/:deviceId/messages', function ( req, res ) {
  var query = azure.TableQuery
    .select()
    .top( 30 )
    .from( "MessageTable" )
    .where( 'PartitionKey eq ?', req.params.deviceId );

  tableService.queryEntities( query, function (error, entities) {
    if ( null != error ) {
      res.end('Could not query MessagesTable: ' + error.code);
      return;
    }
    res.send( entities );
  });
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

[EDIT by @smarx]:

Simpler repro:

```
tableService.createTableIfNotExists('testtable', function () {
  tableService.insertEntity('testtable', {
    PartitionKey: 'pkey',
    RowKey: '2520801590159999999'
  }, function () {
    tableService.queryEntity('testtable', 'pkey', '2520801590159999999', function (error, entity) {
      console.log(entity.RowKey); // prints 2520801590160000000
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Azure Table Storage always stores the PartitionKey and RowKey as a string, no matter how your client library represents it. You may be able to avoid the issue by using strings on the client side as well. Perhaps you can get the RowKey from whatever set the "id" or "link" fields?

Comment: Could you explain more about where the JSON you pasted comes from? Is it the result of a query? What function in the library is returning you this JSON? A quick glance at the code that parses server responses makes it look like strings should be properly treated as strings (not coerced into numbers). Maybe you could write a short program that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @smarx - updated the question with a code sample

Comment: @kenxl I updated it again with a smaller repro. It's probably time to file a bug at the GitHub repo, but I'll take a quick stab at finding the problem myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/util/atomhandler.js.

The implementation of `parse` (by default) tries to guess the type of a property value if none is specified, which I don't believe is the correct behavior. (The lack of a type means to use the default, which is string.)

I've filed a bug (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/114), including a suggested fix. You can try it yourself by just adding `convertTypes = false` at the top of the `parse` function.

**Edit**: This has now been fixed in the repo. (Click on the GitHub issue link above to see.)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript mandates that numbers use [IEEE-754 floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).  The short answer is that it can represent integers exactly up to about 15 digits but your number is longer so it gets rounded to the nearest representable number per that specification.  (The long answer involves an explanation of the number of bits used for the exponent but has the same result.)

It sounds like node-azure should be using strings instead of numbers...